# Find the surface area of part of cone $x^{2} = y^{2} + z^{2}$ which lies inside the sphere $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = 2z$.

Tags: calculus

Find the surface area of part of cone $x^{2} = y^{2} + z^{2}$ which lies inside the sphere $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = 2z$

Intersection of both surfaces on $yz$ plane will be $ y^{2} + (z-1/2)^{2} = 1/4$

Surface area $= \int \sqrt{1 + (y/x)^{2} + (z/x)^{2}} dydz$

$= \int (\sqrt{ (x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}})/x) dydz$

$= \int ( \sqrt{ 2(y^{2} + z^{2})})/(\sqrt{y^{2} + z^{2}}) dydz$

$= \int \sqrt{2} dydz$

Since area of the circle $ y^{2} + (z-1/2)^{2} = 1/4$ is $ \pi /4$ so the surface area should be $( \sqrt{2} \pi)/4$
But answer is given $ \sqrt{2} \pi$

So where did I go wrong$?$

Comment: Given answer can't be correct. $\pi\sqrt{2}$ is the total area of the cone in $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]\times[0,1]$, of which the part that lies in the sphere is a subset.

Answer (score 1):

The condition $ x^2 = y^2 + z^2 $ implies the existence of two cones
$x = \sqrt {y^2 + z^2}$ and $x = -\sqrt {y^2 + z^2}$ so the result should be doubled, as you only used the first cone.

However, the expected answer still remains different.

Comment: Yes, this is what I guessed. Then the result should be $\pi / \sqrt{2}$. But answer is given different.